# webpack: ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' .jsx

Tags: babeljs, reactjs, webpack-2

Using this `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
// autoprefixer configuration based on Bootstrap 4.x defaults
const autoprefixerBrowsers = require('bootstrap/grunt/postcss').autoprefixer.browsers;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    // Set up an ES6-ish environment
    'babel-polyfill',
    "./entry.js",
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  eslint: {
    configFile: './.eslintrc'
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",

        // Skip any files outside of your project's `src` directory
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'entry.js')
        ],

        // Only run `.js` and `.jsx` files through Babel
        test: /\.jsx?$/,

        // Options to configure babel with
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff(2)?)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?/,
        loader: 'url'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('./style.css', {
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      'Tether': 'tether',
      'window.Tether': 'tether'
    })
  ],
  postcss: function () {
    return [
      require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
      require('autoprefixer')({browsers: autoprefixerBrowsers})
    ];
  }
};
```

Having this structure:

```
- src
  - course
    - Courses.jsx
    - CourseList.jsx
  - index.js
```

And this `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import App from './app.jsx'
import About from './about.jsx'
import Courses from './course/Courses';
import {loadCourses} from './actions/courseActions';
import {Router, Route, hashHistory} from 'react-router'

const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(loadCourses());

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/courses" component={Courses}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

And `Courses.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as courseActions from '../actions/courseActions';
import CourseList from './CourseList';

class CoursesPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

  }

  render() {
    const {courses} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Courses</h1>
        <CourseList courses={courses}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    // state.courses = rootReducer.courses
    courses: state.courses
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(courseActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CoursesPage);
```

And `CourseList.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import CourseListRow from './CourseListRow';

const CourseList = ({courses}) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Length</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {courses.map(course =>
        <CourseListRow key={course.id} course={course}/>
      )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
};

export default CourseList;
```

When running `webpack`, I get this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./CourseList in /Users/alex/src/hellowebpack/src/course
 @ ./src/course/courses.js 39:18-41
```

When renaming my `.jsx` files extensions to `.js` it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `resolve` to your webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    packageMains: ['webpack', 'browser', 'web', 'browserify', ['jam', 'main'], 'main'],
}
```

The `extensions` tag will allow you to not include the extension. Notice you are doing this: `import CourseListRow from './CourseListRow';`. That means that you need to add the `resolve` so it resolves the extension.